# Using definitive article or possessive pronoun?

Tags: possessives, definite-articles

I have the following sentence:

> By selecting an element, a dialogue box opens in which the user selects or defines distinguishing features of the anchor node based on the **node’s attributes** (e.g. id , class), **the** whole text or a pattern in **the** text.

An alternative with possessive pronoun is:

> By selecting an element, a dialogue box opens in which the user selects or defines distinguishing features of the anchor node based on **its attributes** (e.g. id , class), **its** whole text or a pattern in **its** text.

That is an example, and there are many cases that I don't know to use "the" or "its"....

Which option is preferred? or a combination of both? How can I factor the repeated "its"?

Answer (score 2):

Both possessive pronouns and articles are determiners, so in many cases, such as in your example, it is a matter of style or preference, that is: do you want to refer to the nouns by an article or a pronoun? To the repetition of *its* sounds bad here. I wouldn't mix and match unless you know what you're doing, that is, until you have a much greater command of English that you have now.